# Is Zam Wesell inspired by early Ralp McQuarrie Concept Art of Han Solo & Starkiller Hero?

Tags: star-wars, inspiration, reference

I was recently looking at some early McQuarrie concept art (and my 30th anniversary action figures based on them) commissioned for George Lucas' [second draft](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Adventures_of_the_Starkiller,_Episode_I:_The_Star_Wars), which would eventually become *A New Hope*.

It occurred to me that both concepts for *Han Solo & Starkiller Hero* featured a great deal of **purple aesthetics** in their overall look or clothing.

It also occurred to me that there really isn't a lot of purple aesthetic in *Star Wars* as it currently stands on film today with a few instances, such as a lightsaber color or Sabine Wren's helmet (and sometimes hair has purple highlights), along with two characters that sport a lot of purple, such as Admiral Holdo & **bounty hunter Zam Wesell.**

[image: Zam]

Zam Wesell's appearance, which comes off as more action-ready, reminds me then a great deal of both Han Solo & Starkiller Hero as they once appeared in concept and therefor **I was wondering, is Zam Wesell inspired by these two early concepts from artist Ralph McQuarrie?**

Comment: Note: Don't get me wrong, there seems to be traces of Soviet-Russian, Japanese Samurai, and maybe a twinge of Western Frontier (in the metal work on the boot) in the stylization of Zam's appearance, but I was still interested if it still was also inspired from the McQuarrie artl too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Zam was based on early concept art for clone troopers for Attack of the Clones

From *The Art of Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones*:

> Concept art for prototypal stormtroopers and assassins was being prepared when Natividad turned in a sketch of a charging trooper, a design Lucas asked him to develop into the bounty hunter and assassin Zam. "For my early stormtrooper sketch, I wanted to indicate it was a human, not a robot, so I had the mask attach to the breastplate," Natividad explained. "George stamped it 'OK' and chose it as the bounty hunter. I tried to do some modifications, but George always wanted more of the original sketch."
>
> (page 34)

Accompanying the page is this concept art:
[image: Concept art for Zam Wesell]

(image sourced from [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/zam-wesell--227783693627366890/), matches the concept art book's layout with the text removed)

From here, this went through a couple of prototyping stages to wind up as Zam's costume:

[image: Postcard showing Zam concept art, model, and final costume]

(source: [The Star Wars Collector's Archive](http://theswca.com/index.php?action=disp_item&item_id=51868), postcard from 2003 Art of Star Wars exhibition)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know if I truley buy that it looks like a modification of stormtrooper design say for the helmet, and there is no mention of how the color purple was decided on/concieved either seemingly (????), but this is still an interesting find! from offical sourse! If no one else comes up with anything else soon, I will check yours off the main answer! :)

Comment: @DarthLocke Yeah, unfortunately no mention of the source of the purple coloration that I've been able to find. The designer of the physical costume itself does talk about how it almost caused issues while filming in https://www.starwars.com/news/clones-at-20-trisha-biggar-interview, but doesn't say whose idea the purple was.

Answer (score -2):

The only reliable source about the creation of the character is [on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zam_Wesell/Legends#Behind_the_scenes)

If a resemblance between McQuarrie's Starkiller concept art and Wesell attire occurred, it looks like it was fortuitous.

Comment: With regards to your two latest answers: please don't just drop a link, even if it's to a well-written page :)  Admittedly a _Star Wars_ Wikia link won't rot, but it'd be better to [edit] your answer so that the relevant information is right here on that SFF thread.

Comment: Although I appreciate your answer and suspect that Wookiepedia updates their information often and is a primary source for SW information, it is possible that not every detail of everything is there in it's entirely, such as Star Wars Art: Ralph McQuarrie (which I unfortunately don't own) and some book like that could shed light on something like this. More and more information comes out all the time too, as new material is released.

Comment: @Jenayah : I understand.  I tried for 20 minutes to formulate an answer that wouldn't look like a "copy-paste" version of the article but i finally gave up.  I will do better in the future.

Comment: @DarthLocke I found a concept art picture of the character : http://www.powerofcostume.si.edu/zamWeselll.html